# Localizing the jQuery UI TimePicker plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I've been using this wonderful [Adding a Timepicker to a jQuery UI Datepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/)

In my example I am using an HTML `select` to change the locale of my calendar (English and Italian).
I have been able to localize the `datepicker` inside the calendar, but I am unable to localize the `timePicker` inside the same.

I would like to change the `timeText`, `hourText` and `minuteText` but cannot figure a way out.
For example it would like to change `hourText` from **"Hour"** to **"Ora"**

I have tried

```
$(".order-date").datetimepicker("option", "timeText", currentCulture == "en" ? "Time" : "Tempo");
$(".order-date").datetimepicker("option", "hourText", currentCulture == "en" ? "Hour" : "Ora");
$(".order-date").datetimepicker("option", "minuteText", currentCulture == "en" ? "Minute" : "Minuto");
```

But this is not working. What am I missing here?

Demo of what I have done till now: http://jsfiddle.net/naveen/qysVp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way and as I didn't find any dynamic way to change the text through option, You can use the following code to achieve this

```
 var timeText =  currentCulture == "en" ? "Time" : "Tempo";
 var hourText =  currentCulture == "en" ? "Hour" : "Ora";
 var minuteText  =  currentCulture == "en" ? "Minute" : "Minuto";

 $(".order-date").datetimepicker('destroy');
 $(".order-date").datetimepicker({
        ampm: true,
        hourText : hourText,
        minuteText: minuteText,
        timeText: timeText,

 });
 $(".order-date").datetimepicker("option", $.datepicker.regional[currentCulture]);
```

By destroying and reinitiating datepicker with updated settings.

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/qysVp/4/)